# Refactor methods - pass in property name

Tags: c#

I'm wondering if it's possible to refactor these two methods into one. The only difference is in the Select method; one uses BaselineSetNumber, the other ComparisonSetNumber.

```
public Set LoadBaselineSet(ObservableCollection<Set> sets)
{
    using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        var setNumber =
            db.Users.Where(x => x.Login == Environment.UserName)
                    .Select(x => x.BaselineSetNumber).Single(); // !!! HERE
        return sets.Single(x => x.SetNumber == setNumber);
    }
}

public Set LoadComparisonSet(ObservableCollection<Set> sets)
{
    using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        var setNumber =
            db.Users.Where(x => x.Login == Environment.UserName)
                    .Select(x => x.ComparisonSetNumber).Single(); // !!! HERE
        return sets.Single(x => x.SetNumber == setNumber);
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a method that I can call like `LoadSet(sets, BaselineSetNumber);` or `LoadSet(sets, ComparisonSetNumber);`

Comment: You can do it like LoadSet(sets, x => x.BaseLineSetNumber) if you extract the predicate from Select as parameter (probably a generic type needs to be used).

Comment: There are only 2 types right now, I might need to add more later though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible by creating a [higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). Your new code would look something like this:

```
public Set LoadBaselineSet(ObservableCollection<Set> sets)
{
    return LoadSet(sets, (x) => x.BaselineSetNumber)
}

public Set LoadComparisonSet(ObservableCollection<Set> sets)
{
    return LoadSet(sets, (x) => x.ComparisonSetNumber)
}

public Set LoadSet(ObservableCollection<Set> sets, Func<dbObject, Int> elementIdentity){
        using (var db = _contextFactory.GetContext())
    {
        var setNumber =
            db.Users.Where(x => x.Login == Environment.UserName)
                    .Select(elementIdentity).Single(); // !!! HERE
        return sets.Single(x => x.SetNumber == setNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: A little tip for refactoring this: if you have Resharper installed then you can select the lambda in the editor and press Ctrl+R, Ctrl+P (Introduce Parameter) to make it a little more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for the response. In the Func parameter declaration I had to change it to Func<User, int?> then it worked great.