# Passing field name to the linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

In a method something like this:

```
public List<Teachers> GetEligibleTeachers(string fieldname)
{
  var query = from t in this.Context.Teachers
              // some more joins and logic , etc..
              where t.custom_field == true
 // .... rest of the query
}
```

I have hardcoded the name of the field in the where clause to `custom_field` but is there is a way I can pass that as a parameter to my method? so for example could have `a.custom_field , a.field2 , a.teahcer_id , etc....`

Comment: Not without reflection. Are you willing to go that far?

Comment: You should look into [`Expression Trees`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx).  You might find a [`Predicate Builder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) to be of great use.

Comment: You don't need reflection as long as you know the field name in the calling function

Comment: you can use a predicate for this

Comment: @GayotFow something like  reggaeguitar answer? please read the comments I posted there.

Comment: @DevWannaBe, almost.  But having said that, I think the design/strategy may be misconceived.  If the 'where' clause cannot be resolved to an explicit condition given what's been provided in the linq projection, then it's the wrong tool for the job.  Sorry.....

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a higher ordered function (see [Refactor methods - pass in property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703563/refactor-methods-pass-in-property-name)) like this

```
public List<Teachers> GetTeachers()
{
    return GetEligibleTeachers(x => x.fieldname);
}

public List<Teachers> GetEligibleTeachers(Func<Teachers, bool> elementIdentity)
{
   var query = Context.Teachers.Where(elementIdentity == true) // rest of query
}
```

Comment: one big problem: x.fieldname : fieldname is not a member of Teachers table. Notice I have a bunch of joins, it is on one of the other tables.

Comment: I guess you will need reflection or expression trees then, it's beyond my expertise

Comment: @DevWannaBe - If the joins are always the same, then just take a `Func<OtherClass, bool>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with something like this:

```
public List<Teachers> GetEligibleTeachers(Func<Teachers, bool> predicate)
{
  var query = this.Context.Teachers.Where(predicate);
 // .... rest of the query
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var result = GetEligibleTeachers(t => t.SomeField == "SomeValue");
```